# Tic tac toe rutorial : How can I trigger multiple callback functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The tutorial avoids using nested components doing this:

```
  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Suppose one wanted to nest the cells inside a row like this:

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <div onClick={props.onClick} className="square">
      [{props.row}.{props.cell}]
    </div>
  );
}

function Row(props) {
  return <div className="row">{props.children}</div>;
}

function Cells(props) {
  let squares = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
    squares.push(<Square row={props.row} cell={i} onClick={props.onClick} />);
  }
  return squares;
}
```

Then Inside Board class how one would create a callback with both row and column? I'm able to pass row, but I can't see how to pass the column click as this is actually inside Cells. The state is lifted up in Board.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      board: [
        [{ value: 1, visible: 0 }, { value: 2, visible: 0 }],
        [{ value: 2, visible: 0 }, { value: 1, visible: 0 }]
      ],
      player_turn: 0, //0,1,2,3
      player1: 0,
      player2: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    alert(e.row + "." + e.cell);
  }

  renderSquares() {
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
      let event = { row: i, cell: -1 };
      rows.push(
        <Row>
          <Cells
            row={i}
            values={this.state.board[i]}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(event)}
            event={event}
          />
        </Row>
      );
    }
    return rows;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderSquares()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass down `column` and `handleClick`! Check out the code below. And I don't really see what the `Cells` component is doing, so didn't keep that, but you could achieve the same thing even if you kept `Cells`. Now `Row` has a bunch of `Squares` as children which makes sense to me :)

```js
function Square({ row, column, onClick, cell }) {
  return (
    <div className="square" onClick={() => onClick({ row, column, ...cell })}>
      [{row}.{column}]
    </div>
  );
}

function Row({ children }) {
  return <div className="row">{children}</div>;
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      board: [
        [{ value: 1, visible: 0 }, { value: 2, visible: 0 }],
        [{ value: 2, visible: 0 }, { value: 1, visible: 0 }]
      ],
      playerTurn: 0, //0,1,2,3
      player1: 0,
      player2: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick({ row, column, value, visible }) {
    let { playerTurn } = this.state;
    playerTurn++;
    this.setState({ playerTurn });
    alert(`${row}.${column} - value: ${value}, visible: ${visible} - player turn: ${playerTurn}`);
  }

  renderSquares() {
    return this.state.board.map((cells, row) => (
      <Row key={row}>
        {cells.map((cell, column) => (
          <Square
            cell={cell}
            key={column}
            row={row}
            column={column}
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          />
        ))}
      </Row>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderSquares()}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Board />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></app>
```